# Add a static method to class and delegate to an existing method

Tags: java, spring, byte-buddy

Here's what I have. An agent:

```
public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) throws Exception {
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .type(ElementMatchers.named("org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication"))
            .transform(new SpringApplicationTransformer())
            .installOn(inst);
}
```

and a transformer:

```
@Override
public Builder<?> transform(Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription,
        ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule module) {
    try {
        builder = builder
                .defineMethod("run", classLoader.loadClass(
                        "org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext"),
                        Modifier.PUBLIC | Modifier.STATIC)
                .withParameter(Class.class).withParameter(String[].class)
                .intercept(MethodCall
                        .invoke(named("run").and(isStatic()
                                .and(takesArguments(Object.class, String[].class))))
                        .withAllArguments());
        return builder;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

I can see in a debugger that the transformer is called and completes successfully, but I still can't call that method:

```
$ java -javaagent:target/spring-boot-legacy-agent-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-agent.jar -jar target/spring-boot-legacy-agent-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --thin.profile=old
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.launch(ThinJarWrapper.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.main(ThinJarWrapper.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.launch(ThinJarLauncher.java:186)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.main(ThinJarLauncher.java:133)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext;
at com.example.AgentApplication.main(AgentApplication.java:10)
... 15 more
```

Adding a listener to the agent builder gets me some more information:

```
ava.lang.IllegalStateException: class org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication does not define exactly one virtual method for (name(equals(run)) and hasParameter(hasTypes(erasures(containing(is(class java.lang.Object;), is(class [Ljava.lang.String;))))))
at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodCall$MethodLocator$ForElementMatcher.resolve(MethodCall.java:668)
at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodCall$Appender.apply(MethodCall.java:2002)
...
```

So it looks like the method matcher isn't matching. There *is* a static method there with those parameter types, but it's not in the list when it is filtered. I must be missing something for static methods?

I did manage to get it to work with javassist, but I'd like to understand why byte-buddy isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matcher API is only meant for dynamically detecting virtual calls where this type-relative detection can make sense, mainly due to generics. For static methods, you do however know the exact type that declares a method as well as the method's types and you should therefore supply a reference to the static method instead:

```
MethodCall.invoke(typeDescription
                   .getDeclaredMethods()
                   .filter(named("run")
                     .and(isStatic()
                     .and(takesArguments(Object.class, String[].class)))
                   .getOnly()).withAllArguments())
```

This is also mentioned in the javadoc of the method you were using:

> Invokes a unique **virtual** method of the instrumented type that is matched by the specified matcher.

I should however give a bit more background on why the API is built that way.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe some more examples in the README or something would help?

Comment: No doubt, I should write more documentation but there is always to little time for everything. Jigsaw kept me quite busy the recent year.